# Recovering lost types while avoiding 'unchecked cast' warning

Tags: java, generics

I have an object where the type of generic `T` is lost at some point through a giant interface chain. I was wondering if it is possible to use a function to regain some type safety by checking the types:

```
private T metaData; // type of T is lost
public <R> R getMetaData(Class<R> className) {
    assert className.isInstance(metaData);
    return (R) metaData;
}
```

However, this implementation produces an "Unchecked cast: 'T' to 'R'" warning. Is there an implementation that avoids this warning, or is the only solution to suppress it?

Comment: Basically, `Class.cast` is a method that already has the @SuppressWarning annotation. The conversion is still unchecked.

Comment: Does this actualy improve anything? You'll get an assertion error instead of a class cast exception, what is the big difference?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You don't have to cast to `R` with `()`, you could use the `Class` directly instead. Like,

```
return className.cast(metaData);
```

which doesn't cause any warnings here.

Comment: You could add that this throws a potential `ClassCastException` when the object is not null and is not assignable to `R` (although it's not possible in this scenario).